# Where can I find detailed information on all steps for Spark Physical plan?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So I am completely new to Spark and I am trying to use Spark WebUI to read plans, dags and stuff like that. And honestly I found lack of informations on spark physical, logical e.t.c plans very disturbing.  For example I was looking for 2 hours straight  tryna find information on such thing as BatchScan step in Physical Plan. So my question is: is there some sort of enciclopedia for that sort of things with all parameters explained?  Is there may be at  least some sort of  cheatsheet for some basic  spark query plan steps?

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best single source of knowledge fro Spark SQL details is this book by [Jacek Laskowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305344/jacek-laskowski): [The Internals of Spark SQL](https://books.japila.pl/spark-sql-internals/query-execution/)

Here you can find high-level description of component but also detailed descriptions for each step (you can try to use search to find docu for BatchScan)

You can also always take a look at Spark source code, here for example you can see code for [BatchScanExec](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/BatchScanExec.scala)

Answer (score -1):

A curated list of Apache Spark resources that may you will find useful. Focused on Apache Spark resources for different use cases. It include the following resources:

- Books
- Links
- Tutorials
- Courses
- Papers
- MOOCS
- Workshops
- Projects Using Spark
- Docker Images
- Miscellaneous
- Tools
- Videos

The first link is  [here](https://github.com/sumitarora/awesome-spark) and [here](https://github.com/awesome-spark/awesome-spark).

Generally, you can find plenty of information on the above links to expand your knowledge with the latest resources related to Apache Spark with tools,books,paper etc. that existed and were tested before by other developers. It's an awesome list and must be added to your read list immediately. I hope you will find my notation here valuable. Cheers!!!

Unfortunately for BatchScanExec the only useful thing I found is this documentation https://books.japila.pl/spark-sql-internals/physical-operators/BatchScanExec/